# Enable resource shrinking for only one build flavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type, android-build-flavors

Is it possible to write build.gradle file to have resource shrinking enabled for only one build flavor? Currently we can enable shrinking per build type, can we have build types per flavor

Answer (score 0):

There are three notion in `gardle` build system.

> Build type
>   Build flavor
>   Build varinat

Build varinat is the combination of Build type and build falvor.

For example you have release and debug build types and you have free and paid falvors.

There will be four build variants

> freeDebug
>   freeRelease
>   paidDebug
>   paidRelease

If your `release` build type is with shrinking you can add new release named `realese2` without shrinking there will added two build variants more

> freeRelease2
>   paidRelease2

When you want falvor with shrinking build `falvorRelease` and dont want shrinkg build with `falvorRelease2`